# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'portal.Models.SubProjectViewRecord'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got this simple code that will consume api json array from a url.

```
public ActionResult ViewRecord()
        {

            ViewBag.Title = "- Geotagging Sub Project Record.";
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookievalue");
            string objJson = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://test.com/api/lib_region");

             //here we will map the Json to C# class
            Models.SubProjectViewRecord oop = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.SubProjectViewRecord>(objJson);                                                                                                               
            return View(oop);
            
    }
```

my model

```
namespace portal.Models
{
    public class SubProjectViewRecord
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The error of the code above is:

```
'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'portal.Models.SubProjectViewRecord' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.'
```

then these are the fixes I apply to model as some reply being posted.

```
public class SubProjectViewRecord
        {
            public List<string> Name { get; set; }
            public List<int> Id { get; set; }
        }
```

to this line:

```
Models.SubProjectViewRecord oop = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.SubProjectViewRecord>>(objJson);
```

but the error raised:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<portal.Models.SubProjectViewRecord>' to 'portal.Models.SubProjectViewRecord'
```

Comment: What does the json look like?

Comment: A dictionary inside array [{"Id" : ""}, {"Name":""}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently looks like from the error that there are multiple items in the array that is why there is any array returned from the api reponse. you can use a `List<T>` for it and the code for it would be like :

```
List<Models.SubProjectViewRecord> oop = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.SubProjectViewRecord>>(objJson);
```

While your model would be below assuming that the json array elements are of **json object** with `Id` and `Name` members in it:

```
public class SubProjectViewRecord
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need to know how is your data returned by your JSON. So, if you have something like that:

```
[
  {
    "name": "",
    "id": ""
  }
]
```

What you'll need is a list of a class that implements a structure like that (like SubProjectViewRecord). So, you'll have something like that:

```
List<SubProjectViewRecord> oop = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubProjectViewRecord>>(objJson);
```

And if you see, that is exactly what your error says. It says: "I cannot assign a List to a SubProjectViewRecord variable".

So, just be sure of:

- Your class matches exactly with your JSON structure.
- The class that you provide for the deserialization (the generic that you pass on DeserializeObject) is the same as the variable that will receive the deserialization.